# Git: Best Practice for Changing Only Master but not Develop

Tags: git, version-control

I have two branches, `master` and `develop`. `master` deploys to a production environment, and `develop` deploys to a development environment.

I want to make a change to `master` that involves deleting a large amount of code. However, I don't want to make this same change to `develop`.

In this situation, is it OK for me to make a branch off of `master` (let's call it `update-master`), delete all the unwanted code on `update-master`, and then merge it back into `master`, but leave `develop` as-is? If I do this, will I be able to merge `develop` back into `master` later on, or will the unique merge from `update-master` prevent me from merging `develop` back into `master`?

Comment: It should be fine, but if you changed the deleted files in `develop`, you will get merge conflicts when merging from `develop` to the new `master` (after `update-master` was merged).

Comment: This depends on what the relationship is between `develop` and `master`. In general, it's not a good idea to have them purposefully diverged if you plan to merge them later. Why don't you want to merge `master` into `develop`? (i.e. Why don't you want the deletions to be in `develop` also?) Re-wording the same question, why do you want to delete code from `master` that you still "like"?

Comment: @TTT `master` is code to a production website. `develop` is code to the dev version of the website. `develop` was split from `master` when master was in an incomplete / bad state. `develop` continued being developed without `master` being fixed. Now, I want to fix `master`, but `develop` isn't ready to be merged into master and won't be ready for some time. Therefore, I want to make a change only to `master` and then merge `develop` back into `master` later on, once it's ready.